# How much is it possible to fake age?

Tags: biology, time, modern-age

There's a society with a privileged class of people. Privileged - because the period of time when they can be part of that class is limited. Only people between 20 and 30 years old can be admitted and only maximum of 5 years is allowed to be in that class (the limitation still holds: admitted at 27 will be able to stay within till 30, so, 3 years)

Sam is smart. And also resourceful. He knows that benefits of being within that class of people are immense. And he has *connections*. He can fake the identity (like - passport) and bribe some authorities because being within that class of people worth more.

So Sam's plan is: go in and then after reaching 30 resign, fake identity and apply again. And here is the thing: he can fake the passport, but can he fake the appearance? It may work once (let's say 30 years old vs 35 years old), but then?

The society tech is just modern, 2020 stuff. Sam can spend a lot of money on ideas like plastic surgery.

**Question is - using our level of technology, for how long can Sam fake his age so that he stays within that below 30 age range visually?**

***EDIT (some clarifications):***

- Whether or not there are some records checks is irrelevant. Let's assume that there are such checks (passport/biometrics/...) but Sam can cheat it because he can influence authorities
- The job Sam wants to do has limited publicity: it is private for external observers but public to within the group (meaning *within the group Sam had joined*)
- Sam needs to keep his appearance young because he can't hide his face from the group. People will start asking questions and it's not going to end well for Sam. These people are his coworkers, not professional medics or anything.
- Sam doesn't need to worry about questions like "why is this guy here for more than 5 years" because all people can be part of the group for no more than 5 years - when the 5 years are over, he fakes his id, fakes his age (subject of this question) and when he's back, all the surrounding people will be new so they won't recognize his face: the exposure is only happening to the group Sam joined which will be disbanded after 5 years. No newcomers join existing groups over the course of 5 years.
- The job Sam & his coworkers do is not any VR or anything. It's a regular job in terms of collaboration - daily exposure for potentially several hours in person. They can *see* him and *talk* to him in person.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96225/discussion-on-question-by-alma-do-how-much-is-it-possible-to-fake-age).

Comment: If Sam can get the correct identification, it shouldn't matter what he looks like. You appearance is an informal check and if you look too young or too old for something, then it makes sense to check someones ID for a proper confirmation. If the ID is issued by the proper authorities there isn't much anyone can do, except to escalate it up to a higher level. A real world example would be a bouncer stopping someone who looks 13. Their ID says they are 25. They call the police. The ID is authentic and they are allowed access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to make a man (?) of 30, then 35, then perhaps 40, look 25?

And it has to pass in person, and continue to pass (presumably with regular touch-ups) for five years at a time?

And "Sam" has money and some help, I presume (plastic surgeon, hair and makeup artists, fitness coaches, etc.).

Based on modern movie makeup, it shouldn't be hard at all to get to age forty.  Fill in little lines in the face, cover the beginnings of graying hair, perhaps hair transplants as needed to keep the hairline from receding, more and more aggressive gym time to keep the pot belly away and keep the six-pack, pecs, and biceps good.

Beyond forty, the challenges get bigger.  I started to get "arcus" -- rings of cholesterol at the edges of the corneas -- well before I was fifty.  Someone with very low blood cholesterol might avoid them.  It gets harder and harder, however, past fifty, to stay in shape, and there's more and more of the face to keep filled, and more and more gray in the hair -- plus the gray will show in the beard or, worst, the stubble, often before forty.  My beard had started to go gray by the time I was thirty-five.

I'm going to say it's probably not possible to be convincing much past forty.

Plastic surgery isn't magic.  You can do a little very well, but if you do a lot, it shows.  Remember how Mickey Rourke wound up looking like someone else?  Remember how Carrottop looked like an accident victim?  Even a good surgeon, trying to be subtle, can wind up with a disaster like Michael Jackson's nose.

The best you're going to get even with actual plastic surgery is probably forty-five.

Comment: But plastic surgery? Is it of any good?

Comment: Plastic surgery leaves evidence that's visible to the trained, experienced eye.  The less you have done, but better.  Filling fine lines, no big deal, but a real "lift" is visible.

Comment: But for ordinary people? His coworkers are just common people, not those who were trained for that. It's them who he needs to fool with his appearance. Anything else he can overcome.

Comment: Even then, getting past fifty likely won't fly.  How many times have you heard "she's had some work done" about a female celebrity?  Remember when Carotttop had his face "fixed"?  Or Mickey Rorke?

Answer (score 2):

Can Sam bribe a medical facility and "diagnose" himself as having **[Progeroid syndromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progeroid_syndromes)**
?

Progeroid syndromes basically are rare diseases that patients ages faster than normal human. If Sam can get new IDs and whatnot, he should be able to get a doctor's certification that he has such diseases.

Normally people wouldn't suspect their co-worker as faking a disease like this, it would be too discriminating. And for social politeness, people don't even ask too much about others rare disease.

One example would be, *[Werner syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_syndrome)*, which leads to premature graying of hair, hair loss, wrinkling, prematurely aged faces.

Comment: This is an interesting concept. I will consider it as a backup option, thanks! It doesn't answer the challenge but nevertheless is an interesting insight

Comment: @AlmaDo I agree. On a side note, I've *heard that Vladimir Putin is obsessed with plastic surgery / other ways to keep him looks tough and young. He can pretty much get the best medical/cosmetic support in the world, and if that rumor is true, that shows how much younger can 2020 technology makes.